# EURT Tempo Crypto page down

Tags: token

I am trying to find API documentation for the Tempo EURT. I have been digging around and it seems that what used to be their web page: "tempocrypto.com" is down, as well as their other page "k.tempocrypto.com". I am struggling to find API documentation regarding this topic, please can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The api supports sep6/sep24

here is some directions on getting started.

https://github.com/antb123/stellar-payment-api and the end point is https://k.tempocrypto.com

thanks